# Excel vlookup and if

Tags: excel

Ok so I am fairly new to using excels formula functions and I am still learning. What I am trying to do is combine two statements both work independently but I need them together. the two statements are an if statement and a vlookup and are as follows

```
=IF(C5>=$J$4,"YES","NO")
=VLOOKUP(C6-500,$H$5:$I$8,2)
```

The vlookup needs to take the spot of the yes part in the if so I don't get the error message that get because some values are below the threshold for the vlookup but I want to simply say that they are not valid hence the if statement.

If there are any better ways to do this I am all ears.

Comment: Sample data is always helpful for visitor to understand question. See answer below. If you need any clarification then let us know by comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put `VLookup()` in the yes part then put the formula as below.

```
=IF(C5>=$J$4,VLOOKUP(C6-500,$H$5:$I$8,2),"NO")
```

If you want to control `errors` by formula then use `IFERROR()` function. Like

```
=IFERROR(IF(C5>=$J$4,VLOOKUP(C6-500,$H$5:$I$8,2),"NO"),"")
```

`IFERROR()` with `VLookup()` only.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6-500,$H$5:$I$8,2),"")
```

Comment: Thank You That worked looking back at what I had I think there was an extra punctuation mark or space.